# 500 Internal Server Error in Smarty?

Tags: php, logging, smarty, internal-server-error

I got 500 Internal Server Error. I fetch the data from mysql using php file and assign a Smarty variable, and printing in tpl file.

There are 23k data records. If I echo (printing all value) in PHP file I get all data. but while loading in smarty it through 500 error. while loading the tpl file in Smarty.

I checked access.log, error.log files and does not show any error. I checked many solution but all are fails.

Comment: Please note that if you are asking people to upvote your own material, that would be regarded as voting fraud. The odds of this question (which is off-topic even after I trimmed the [ASAP begging](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) out of it) getting +3 in an organic fashion is quite low, I would say.

Comment: To make this question on-topic, please edit it so that a reader would have a good chance of reproducing the problem. Do you perhaps have error logging turned off in your PHP installation?

Answer (score 0):

You have 23k data records in one folder?

While printing all values in PHP but while loading "500 internal server error "?

**Solution**: It's due to PHP's maximum execution timeout and memory usage. Just increase the values in your `php.ini` as you need.

Enable the Output buffering too...

```
max_execution_time = 300 ; //5mins max increase as per your need
memory_limit = 256M ; //Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (256MB)
```

*That's all, if it shows the error again, increase the values.*

But I recommend this method to output the 23k data records:
Just create a table in MySQL, insert all the 23k data, and retrieve it. This is the finest method and faster that avoids PHP variable stitching.